# NetworkStream BeginRead only reads once?

Tags: c#, networkstream

I have some pretty simple code that reads lines from a network stream that it connects to.  In the code example only one line is every read and it doesn't carry on getting more from the server.

What is wrong?

```
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        byte[] tempBuff = new byte[1024];
        int tempBuffSize = 0;    


private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("192.168.1.151", 5505);
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, 1024, readHandler, tcpClient); 
        }

void readHandler(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)result.AsyncState;
            int dataLen = tcpClient.GetStream().EndRead(result);

            int currStart = 0;
            int currEnd = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; i++)
            {
                if (readBuffer[i] == '\r' && i < (readBuffer.Length - 1) &&
                    readBuffer[i + 1] == '\n')
                {
                    // Set the end of the data 
                    currEnd = i - 1;

                    // If we have left overs from previous runs: 
                    if (tempBuffSize != 0)
                    {

                        byte[] joinedData = new byte[tempBuffSize + (currEnd - currStart + 1)];
                        Array.Copy(tempBuff, 0, joinedData, 0, tempBuffSize);
                        Array.Copy(readBuffer, currStart, joinedData, tempBuffSize, (currEnd - currStart + 1));

                        System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                        string myString = enc.GetString(joinedData);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(myString);

                        tempBuffSize = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                        string myString = enc.GetString(readBuffer);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(myString);

                        // HandleData(readBuffer, currStart, currEnd);
                    }

                    // Set the new start - after our delimiter 
                    currStart = i + 2;
                }

            }

            // See if we still have any leftovers 
            if (currStart < dataLen)
            {
                Array.Copy(readBuffer, currStart, tempBuff, 0, dataLen - currStart);
                tempBuffSize = dataLen - currStart;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should read up on how to get data from network. The problem with network-programming is that you have no guarantee that when the server sends you 1000bytes, you will receive it as 1000bytes, you might receive it as buckets of 100bytes, or first 300, then 600, then 100bytes. That is all "random". Thus you should continue to read from the stream til you got all the data you want. Normally this is done by ending the readHandler with a new call to BeginRead again (thus making a async loop of sorts).

Comment: The above comment should be an answer (except that it is practically the same as my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect it to read the whole information in the first place? I am not an expert but it seems to me that neither the synchronous nor the asynchronous methods guarantee reading all the data (whatever that means because as long as a socket is open more data can arrive). After the code in your EndRead method you should call Read or BeginRead again if you expect more data. You should know if more data is expected based on the protocol you've established with the client.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issues when i developed tcp apps for an embedded device. In my case the problem was the device was giving out data in a delayed time and hence before the rest of the data can come in the control moves to the next line in the program fetching only the initial data from the server. I got around this by introducing a delay.

Just after the line where you read data from the server introduce a delay and for that reason it would be better to run this on a separate thread

```
thread.sleep(3000)
```

This should be your problem most probably.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your stream object got disposed when it got out of scope, before the readHandler could be called again. try promoting tcpClient and stream to class scope instead of method scope, or move the reading to a separate thread that exits when the operation has finished.

Comment: No, I just moved the stream and tcpClient to class scope and no change :-(